# 'No such file or directory' error - tried a bunch of different ways (Python)

Tags: python, directory, directory-structure

I have a set of CSV's inside a folder and I need to perform the same thing on each of the CSV, so I have written a code-snip that looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

PROJECT = r'~/Dropbox/Work/1. Data/'
DATA = '4. Data from AWS/2. Domains/'

for filename in os.listdir(os.path.join(PROJECT, DATA)):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
        print(filename)
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

and I get the error - `No such file or directory: ~/Dropbox/Work/1. Data/4. Data from AWS/2. Domains/`

However, when I try this, `file1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(PROJECT, DATA, "youtube_links.csv"))`, the file opens without a problem. I have more than 3000 files, so loop is the easiest/safest way to calculate the things I want to calculate. I have included `filename = os.fsdecode(filename)` inside the loop and before the `if` statement, same error.

Strangely enough, this code was working perfectly a month ago. I am not sure how to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Python doesn't interpret ``~`` as your home directory unless you tell it to.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - so I did this ```print(os.path.expanduser('~'))``` and it shows the correct directory ```/users/nilima``` where my Dropbox exists.